# Is there a trick to place a boat without adequate space?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since returning to the game (1.8), it seems a change has been made to disallow the placement/spawning of a boat that would intersect with something (at the same height). This makes the construction of a [(vertical) teleboater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnpbHbsPs_k) more difficult, needing to clear out blocks around the block upon which one desires to place a boat. Is there a way to spawn a boat in tight quarters like before, or is it now impossible to do so?

Update: Sand can intersect with a boat by block falling to there, but it seems only at the edge of the boat. Otherwise, the sand block will break upon contact (converting the sand into item drop form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as easy as before but it is still possible with dispensers. Just put boat in dispenser and place water block where dispenser faces. It is possible with flowing water so when you make vertically you only need 1 source block at top. Example :

[image: Put boats in dispensers and power dispensers]

[image: After powering dispensers and removing water]

Comment: Damn, resource-expensive, but cool.

Comment: @NiteCyper It is possible to do this with only 1 dispenser and redstone blocks can be replaced with button or lever (this too can be done with only 1).

Answer (score 1):

No it is now impossible to do so unfortunately. Although if you want to make it easier to get them into place you can do it with minecarts instead of boats and use rails, by doing this you only need a 1x2 instead of a 1x3 hole to fit them into place.